# AngularJS : Getting cached result from $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting cached result while using $http to call an API. Here is the AngularJS code:

```
$scope.validate = function(){

    var encodedUserNameAndPassword = Base64.encode($scope.username + ':' + $scope.password);
    var decode = Base64.decode(encodedUserNameAndPassword);
    $http.defaults.headers.put = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
    };
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encodedUserNameAndPassword;
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/user/jim',cache:false}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log(data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(data);

        });
}
```

Can any one point out what I'm missing.

Comment: try $http.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = encodedUserNameAndPassword;

Answer (score 0):

Don't do $http provider modification inside controller.Do it in configuration level of angular.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule',[]);
myModule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    //initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
    }
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Pragma = "no-cache";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["If-Modified-Since"] = "0";
}]);
```

Most of the time GET request is cached by IE.

Then inside your $http call parameters

```
$http({method: 'GET', 
       url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/user/jim',
       headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic '+ encodedUserNameAndPassword}
          }
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   console.log(data);
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   alert(data);
});
```

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: are you doing any server side caching?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to call a REST API running locally. I tried the API using CURL and its works fine.

Comment: can you try the same thing in chrome private browsing?

Comment: which angular version you're using?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS 1.2.8 . The issue is like , once if I get a success and data, the same data is returned even if the nothing is returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68890/discussion-between-ijay-and-pankajparkar).